# Are gdt segment are ignored by the CPU?

Tags: kernel, gdt

I am studying Kernel development. Using a book I have come to a point. However, I cannot realy understand the affect of global descriptor table. My GDT is as follows:

```
gdt_star:

gdt_null:
dd 0x0      
dd 0x0

gdt_code:
dw 0xffff   
dw 0x0000
db 0x00     
db 10011011b
db 11001111b
db 0x0      

gdt_data:
dw 0xffff
dw 0x0
db 0x00
db 10010010b
db 11001111b
db 0x0              

gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
dw gdt_end - gdt_star - 1
dd gdt_star

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_star
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_star
```

After loading gdt and assigning DATA_SEG to ds, ss, es, fs, gs registers; my assembly code jumps to c code. Data segment base address is 0x00000000 and the limit is 0xffff. Shouldn't it be impossible to put a value to 0x100000 memory address?

Thank you

Comment: You've edited the question to be a different one, by changing the graularity bit. It's almost always a better idea to ask a new question if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is scaled by the granularity.

For example, if you use page granularity (4K), a limit of `0xfffff` will give you access to the entire 4G address space.

The granularity is dictated by (from memory) the second `db` in each `GDT` entry. Because the top bit of that value is `1`, the 4K granularity is selected.

If you look at the following image, you'll see the limits of what you can access in the data segment:

[image]

```
gdt_data:
dw 0xffff     Segment limit b15..b0.
dw 0x0        Base address b15..b0.
db 0x00       Base address b23..b16.
db 10010010b  Present (1 bit) = yes.
              Data protection level (2 bits) = 0 (highest).
              Selector (1 bit) = code/data.
              Type (4 bits) read/write.
db 11001111b  Granularity (1 bit) = 4k.
              32-bit selector (1 bit) = 32 bits.
              Unused (1 bit).
              Segment limit b19..b16.
db 0x0        Base address b31..b24.
```

Hence your base address is `0x0000.0000` and segment limit is `0xf.ffff` with 4k scaling. That allows addresses from `0x0000.0000` up to `0xffff.ffff`. In other words, a full 4G address space.

Comment: Thank you. How can you assign `0xfffff` to a 2 bytes area. Is is a typo?When I change the gdt in accordance with your explanation, I can put value to `0x300000`. I have updated my question will you please check it?

Comment: The base and limit are in multiple sections within the gdt. As well as the 16-bit word, there are more bits in the other values which are used as well. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table for a graphic showing this. Base address has 32 bits and limit has 20 bits.

Comment: Ok. Thank you I understand that. But I still can put data to a memory address which is beyond the limit + base address. Why this happens?